# Explanation of the "posts_join" and "posts_fields" filter hooks?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks

I'm new to the "posts_" filter hooks and wanted to know a few things from those in the know:

In this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy), someone posted an answer using `posts_join` that took a second parameter of `$query`:

```
add_filter('posts_join',array(&$this,'posts_join'),10,2);

...

function posts_join($join,$query) {

}
```

Is this an instance of wp_query or something similar?

Same example:

How would I determine the post type so that I can do custom joins for each custom post type I have on the admin side

What does the `posts_fields` filter hook do?  from the example I've seen, it looks like it replaces the columns in the `SELECT` clause of an `SQL` call.

Am I correct in that assumption, and does it too have more parameters that can be called??

I find some examples but I can't get any solid documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use one of the methods to query for posts (`query_posts()`, `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` object) arguments you provide are processed and turned into SQL query. This happens in `WP_Query->&get_posts()` method.

Since arguments are not omnipotent there are a lot of hooks in there that allow to modify or override parts of resulting SQL query.

- `posts_join` is part of query that handles SQL JOINs - adding additional tables to the mix, for example tables related to taxonomies when they are needed.
- `posts_fields` seem to control which database fields will be returned in query, it seems to default to all fields from `posts` table.

Comment: So basically post_fields replaces the select part of a query.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: Not all of SELECT, it looks like this in code `SELECT $found_rows $distinct $fields FROM` where `$fields` variable is passed through `posts_fields` filter.

Comment: So, if I were to use the posts_fields filter, how would I access the results??  Is there a way to get to the from thw WP_query class?

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond if I am not mistaken `WP_Query->query()` method returns the array of posts you queried for, affected by this filter and all others. They should also be saved in `WP_Query->posts` field after that.

Comment: Note that `get_posts()` defaults to suppressing filters, while `query_posts()` does not: [get_posts() > parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters).