# Sorting posts DESC based on the number of comments using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, comments, order

I have this unusual requirement from my client that I need to accommodate. They want to be able to view the posts with the largest number of comments first.

At first I thought using a [custom select query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) would do the trick. I had to write a subquery to but was able to use a custom select query to implement the functionality. Well, it didn't take me too long to realize that suddenly the [WP Page Numbers](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-page-numbers/installation/) plugin stopped working. Looking at the source code for the plugin I realized it's relying on the `WP_Query` object having been populated in order to figure out the page numbers and navigation stuff.

I can't think of a way to use the `WP_Query` class to do the kinds of sorting I need to do. At the same time, I don't want to have to implement my own pagination functionality because my client (and I) really love the WP Page Numbers plugin.

Before I go down the path of extending the `WP_Query` class as Mike suggested in this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy), I just wanted to reach out to everyone with similar experiences and ask if there is any alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with this?

    `query_posts( 'orderby=comment_count' );`

Comment: OMG, you're kidding!!! Let me give it a shot.

Comment: Let me know if it works... I was using it for a while for my own client who later changed their mind because they realized that that every new post that becomes popular will have to gain that many comments to get to the top of the page :p

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Lynne has you headed in the right direction PFrank.  Check out this page in the WordPress Codex for more info on sorting queries and sorting by 'comment_count'.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Answer (score 1):

The comments already contain an answer to this question, which is:

```
 query_posts( 'orderby=comment_count' );
```

Now, here is a basic equivalent code to use with the `WP_Query` class, since everyone knows not to use `query_posts`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'orderby' => 'comment_count') );
```