# WP 3.1 getting tax_query to work in query_posts()

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization

I'm trying to filter my posts using multiple custom taxonomies for my custom posts with the following code, but I keep getting blanks with my new code i.e. no posts appear in the loop.

It works like this: the user chooses a term for custom taxonomies 'fttype', 'ftperiod' and 'ftduration' from three different  dropdowns in a form, and this is passed to the code below as:

- $ft_t_ns
- $ft_p_ns
- $ft_d_ns

I originally had this code (which works, albeit without pagination), but the new code I'm trying to implement so that I can use WP 3.1's in-built capability of filtering by multiple custom taxonomies isn't working (see my new code further down).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Been fighting with this for a while...

Thanks

osu

**OLD CODE**

```
// Set todays date to check against the custom field StartEventDate
$todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');

// Convert spaces in taxonomies and terms into hyphens so that search works correctly (uses slug)
$ft_t_ns = osu_convert_spaces($ft_t);
$ft_p_ns = osu_convert_spaces($ft_p);
$ft_d_ns = osu_convert_spaces($ft_d);

// Build query
// NOTE: AS OF WP 3.1, SEE V2 FOR HOW TO PASS AN ARRAY TO query_posts(). YOU PROBABLY WON'T NEED
// QUERY MULTIPLE TAXONOMIES PLUGIN EITHER FOR V2'S APPROACH OF PASSING AN ARRAY TO WP_Query() TO WORK.
// READ MORE ON 'MULTIPLE TAXONOMY HANDLING' HERE:
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters
$ft_args = 'post_type=ftevent';
$ft_args .= '&fttype=' . $ft_t_ns;
$ft_args .= '&ftperiod=' .$ft_p_ns;
$ft_args .= '&ftduration=' . $ft_d_ns;
$ft_args .= '&posts_per_page=' . $ft_ppp;
$ft_args .= '&meta_key=StartEventDate&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=' . $todaysDate;
$ft_args .= '&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC&paged=' . $paged;

// Create query
query_posts($ft_args);
```

**NEW CODE**

```
$ft_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ftevent',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'StartEventDate',
            'value' => $todaysDate,
            // Custom field type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 
            // 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'. Default value is 'CHAR'.
            'type' => 'DATE',
            // Operator to test. Possible values are 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN'.
            // We choose 'BETWEEN' because we need to know the date has not passed to show the event
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'fttype',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $ft_t_ns,
            // Operator to test. Possible values are 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN'.
            // We choose 'IN' because we need to make sure the term is in the current array of posts
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ftperiod',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $ft_p_ns,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ftduration',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $ft_d_ns,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    )
);

// Create query
query_posts($ft_args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$todaysDate` needs to be an array of two values to be `BETWEEN` for the compare.

For example if you wanted to use a date range from today to a week in the future, then you might use something like..

```
$todaysDate = array(
    date('Y/m/d'),
    date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+1 week') )
);
```

Or if you wanted to go back in time, then maybe..

```
$todaysDate = array(
    date('Y/m/d'),
    date('Y/m/d', strtotime('-1 week') )
);
```

***Following on from the comments:** try this as the `meta_query` part of your code.*

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'StartEventDate',
        'value' => date('Y/m/d'),
        'type' => 'DATE',
        'compare' => '>=' // more than or equals
    )
)
```

**NOTE:** It's still possible to use the old `>`(more than), `<`(less than) and other meta comparisons with the new `meta_query` args, or at least it looks that way by looking directly at the source.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/meta.php#L355

Hope that helps.

Comment: @t31os - Thanks for this, do you know how I'd compare $todaysDate (Y/m/d) and my Custom Field 'StartEventDate' (which is a date written as YYYY/MM/DD) within my $ft_args?

Comment: @Osu - Please see updated answer.

Comment: @t31os - that's great, seems to have sorted out the ordering and display of custom posts when you first visit the page. Thanks for all your help so far. I'm now trying to figure out why when I submit my form that I get a 404! You've helped me loads already, but if you have the time, it would be great to hear your opinion on why you think that might be happening as you seem to be a Wordpress 'ninja' so to speak - here's my code in pastie for you or anyone interested: http://www.pastie.org/1618788

Comment: Maybe the form isn't always submitting to the correct URL?

Comment: I thought that as well, but as the action of the form is set to nothing, it should be submitting to the same page (using the archive-ftevent.php template) right? Funny enough, when I choose some options from the dropdown, the page loads but the tax_query doesn't seem to be taking effect i.e. it doesn't filter by the terms chosen in the <select> dropdowns. That's a separate issue I'll have to deal with, but I'm assuming the code from lines 34-40 are the problem with the 404...

Comment: Can you add `print '<pre>'; print_r( $ft_args ); print '</pre>'; ` somewhere after your args and give me the results so i can see how they look before they reach the query.

Comment: @t31os - thanks for this, much appreciated. Here's the results when just visiting the page i,e, default state: http://www.pastie.org/1621031 and this is the result when submitting the form (with none of the 'All' dropdown options set i.e. Type, Period and Duration haven't got the default 'All' option set): http://www.pastie.org/1621037

Comment: @Osu, the term part of the tax queries are empty in the first paste, shouldn't they be removed if there's no specific term to select on?

Comment: @t31os - tried that, but it doesn't seem to make things work...any other idea of what I could try? I'm confused why I get a 404 with this when submitted 'All' in any of the dropdowns, yet get results when choosing an option for each dropdown (even if they aren't filtering the posts correctly)...

Comment: Can anyone else help with this? Any ideas of how I can get this filter to work? I'm starting to wonder if this is the best way to do this...

Comment: @Osu - Try adding in `'surpress_filters' => true` to your args, there may be a filter interupting the query.

Comment: @t31os - thanks for your continued patience. I think your comment about removing the 'terms' args when nothing is in them is the solution. How would I not include that argument if no terms are present (i.e. when first visiting the page or when selecting 'All' from the dropdown list)? I thought I'd covered myself with the code that starts `if($ft_t == 'All') { $ft_t = ''; }` But obviously if leaving the terms blank is the problem, it would break the system. How would I use that same code to display all my terms? I tried re-using my function `osu_list_terms_text('fttype');` but it didn't work..

Comment: I'd personally trim down your whole argument building routine to [something like this](http://wpse.pastebin.com/8uH4WJzR). Can you follow what i've done there alright?

Comment: @t31os - That's superb, much nicer! Thanks a lot for this - always good to see simpler ways to do things. Only thing I need to sort is what happens when the user selects 'All' as it's generating a 404 currently - it's definitely to do with the $args from the form being passed to the query, so will focus on that. Once it's all done, I'll post up the full code for anyone interested (what a battle to get this working!). Thanks once again, osu

Comment: I thought i'd accounted for the All / empty case in the code i posted, is it not working as expected?

Comment: @t31os - you have indeed accounted for the All/empty cases. I've drilled it down to one thing that's causing the 404 I think - here's the whole script again, but with comments with how I understand your new code: http://www.pastie.org/1628574. It's the first dropdown (fttype) that's causing the problem - everytime 'All' is selected, I get a 404. Doesn't happen if fttype is set to something other than 'All'...

Comment: @t31os - also noticed that pagination isn't working, but I'll start a new post on that - you've helped me more than enough so far!

Comment: @Osu - The code previously posted was intended to replace all the code before the `query_posts` line, [try this](http://wpse.pastebin.com/U8p9Eu2h).

Comment: @t31os Argh, this is driving me mad! So close, yet I keep getting these 404s. I've decided to omit the 'All' options as I simply can't get the form to work with them (I think the solution for that would be to omit the `'terms' => array( $$query_tax ),` line whenever 'All' or '' is selected, but don't know how  to do that. I'm now getting a 404 whenever two-word terms (like Group walks) are submitted in the form. It's like those terms aren't being sanitized before being passed to `query_posts()`. Here's my latest code (added lines 86-89 to recall <options>): http://www.pastie.org/1628974

Comment: Wasn't sure what you were expecting in the submitted data, get rid of `sanitize_title( $_POST[$query_tax] );` and use `esc_html( $_POST[$query_tax] );` instead. All and empty values should be skipped with the code you have that what's the in_array check does above that line, `continue` basically means skip this result of the loop(foreach loop).

Comment: @t31os - thanks for all your help, I'm reluctant to use any more of your time as you've been so generous so far. This script is working now (http://www.pastie.org/1632301), although I had to remove the 'All' option on the first dropdown as a 404 is produced if no terms are set. I'm going to start a new thread on the paging issue, but I'm appreciative of your assistance, I've learned a lot in the process!

Comment: PS, think I know why leaving 'All' wasn't working - see MikeSchinkel's answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy ("WordPress decides if you don't have a term they'll just ignore your taxonomy")

Comment: It shouldn't matter, the code i provided should only create the tax_query args when a term is selected and is neither `''` (empty), `all` or `All`, i specifically wrote it that way knowing what you wanted. Problem is, i don't have your data on my install so there's going to be some guess work on my part.