# Pagination is not working wp_query custom fields values

Tags: pagination

All

I want those post having post_type == profile And wpcf-gender == 1 (male).

I tried this  code

```
            $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-gender', 'meta_value' => '1', 'meta_compare' => '==', 'post_type' => 'profile','posts_per_page' => 2 ) );
```

Results which I am getting is perfect but pagination is not working. 
Can you please help me to find what is the issue in below code ?

```
<?php


                $temp = $wp_query;
                $wp_query = null;

                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-gender', 'meta_value' => '1', 'meta_compare' => '==', 'post_type' => 'profile','posts_per_page' => 2 ) );
                ?>
                <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">                 
                <h2 class="page-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="page-image">
                        <div class="page-image-overlay-child"></div>
                        <span style="float: left;padding-right: 50px;">
                        <?php 

                            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                            } else {
                                 echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/header-image-1.jpg" alt="" />';
                            }
                        ?>
                        </span>

                        <table>

                            <th></th>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 10px;"><strong>First Name:</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="first-name" class="" style=""]'); ?></td>
                                <td style="padding: 10px;"><strong>Last Name:</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="last-name" class="" style=""]'); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 10px;"><strong>Gender:</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="gender"][/types]'); ?></td>
                                <td style="padding: 10px;"><strong>DOB:</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="dob" style="text" format="F j, Y"][/types]'); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 10px;"><strong>City:</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="city"]'); ?></td>
                                <td style="padding: 10px;"><strong>State:</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="state"]'); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                        <input type="button" value="Read more..." id="searchsubmit" class="readmore" onClick="javascript:location.href = '<?php the_permalink();?>';" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>                 

                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php 

            global $wp_query;

            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
            ));?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add global $paged and then in your array that is being passed to WP_Query you need to add 'paged' => $paged

```
global $paged;
$temp = $wp_query;
                    $wp_query = null;

                    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-gender', 'meta_value' => '1', 'meta_compare' => '==', 'post_type' => 'profile','posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

and so forth

Comment: Thanks it works, edit please $global $paged; To global $paged;