# Pagination in plugin with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have several custom post types (created through CPT UI plugin). I want to display posts from these post types on my page, for example "News". I've created a page and inserted in it shortcode `[show_posts post_type="novyny"].` I've got a plugin that processes this shortcode

```
function foo($args){
    $post_type = $args['post_type'];
    $custom_post_type = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 4
        )
    );

    if( $custom_post_type->have_posts() ) :
        while( $custom_post_type->have_posts() ): $custom_post_type->the_post(); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>
            <p> <?php the_modified_date(); echo ", "; the_modified_time() ?></p>
            <p> <?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
        <?php endwhile;
        the_posts_pagination();
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_shortcode('show_posts', 'foo');
```

Posts are displayed, but pagination blog doesn't appear at the page even if there is more than 4 posts to display. What's wrong?

Comment: pagination functions operate on the main query, you have a custom query. you're also not passing any pagination parameters to the query in the shortcode, so even if you were to visit other pages, you'd get the same results. I suggest searching around here for paginating custom queries, there are no shortage of questions and answers on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_posts_pagination` uses `global` query and global query does not have pagination. So it is the correct behavior of WordPress.

To overcome from this problem assign custom query to global query then after looping again restore the global query.

```
function foo($args){
    $post_type = $args['post_type'];
    global $wp_query;
    $original_query = $wp_query;
    $custom_post_type = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 4
        )
    );

    $wp_query = $custom_post_type;

    if( $custom_post_type->have_posts() ) :
        while( $custom_post_type->have_posts() ): $custom_post_type->the_post(); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>
            <p> <?php the_modified_date(); echo ", "; the_modified_time() ?></p>
            <p> <?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
        <?php endwhile;
        the_posts_pagination();
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $wp_query = $original_query;
}
```

Comment: As Milo suggested, your query does not have pagination parameters. It will always stay at page 1. Read and implement https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all, guys. I've solved it this way:

- added `$paged` variable: `$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` (for **main page** you should use `get_query_var('page')`, for **other pages** - `$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` )
- And added a new argument for WP_Query: `'paged' => $paged`

My code now:

```
function foo($args){
    $post_type = $args['post_type'];

    /* Added $paged variable */
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    global $wp_query;
    $original_query = $wp_query;

    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,

        /* And added a new argument for WP_Query */
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $custom_post_type = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    $wp_query = $custom_post_type;

    if ( $custom_post_type->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $custom_post_type->have_posts() ) :
            $custom_post_type->the_post(); ?>
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>
                <p> <?php the_modified_date(); echo ", "; the_modified_time() ?></p>
                <p> <?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
        <?php endwhile;
        the_posts_pagination();
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    $wp_query = $original_query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small update to Vlad's last post. You need to change

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

to

```
$paged = ( $original_query->query['paged'] ) ? $original_query->query['paged'] : 1;
```

Comment: But that's called before $original_query is initialised, isn't it? If you're using Vlad's code as-is then they should still refer to the correct query.

Comment: '%cpt%/page/2' sets the current page index exactly where I mentioned.  
get_query_var('paged') will return an empty value for cpt. get_query_var refers to ->query_vars, not ->query