# Get list of all custom tanonomy id

Tags: functions, taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy called Location then added New Jersey, New York, etc. Is there a Wordpress function that will get the list of all ids under the Location similar to what get_all_category_ids() does?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this

```
$terms = get_terms("my_taxonomy");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 )
{
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
    {
        echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
 }
```

Otherwise you can also use like this

```
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$args_list = array(
   'taxonomy' => 'item', // or use $taxonomyName for all taxonomies
   'show_count' => true,
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
   'hide_empty' => '0',
   'title_li' => '',
   'echo' => '0',
);
echo wp_list_categories($args_list);
```

Comment: The first code is almost there except that I want to get the list of the id not the name. How do I do that?

Comment: Please try second one for your requirement

Comment: Ohh actually I was able to get the id using your first code. I just replaced the $terms->name with $term->term_id.

Comment: I'm editing a plugin with the code get_all_category_ids() and I know that the code above con't just replace the get_all_category_ids()... how will I be able to rewrite that code you have to be able to replace the get_all_category_ids()?

Comment: Use like this  `<?php 
$args=array(
  'name' => 'Location'
);
$output = 'objects'; // or objects
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->term_id. '</p>';
  }
}  
?>`

Comment: Sorry Bindiya I should have been more clear about it. The code I'm editing shows like this. 

`if (isset($_POST['post_category']))  { $pk = $_POST['post_category']; if (!is_array($pk)) { $pk = urldecode($pk); parse_str($pk); } 
              $cIds = get_all_category_ids(); if(is_array($pk) && $cIds) $options['exclCats'] = serialize(array_diff($cIds, $pk)); else $options['exclCats'] = '';
            }`

So I need to make a function that will replace the get_all_category_ids();

Comment: You can use like this. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'name' => 'Location'
);
$output = 'objects'; // or objects
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {

        $term = term_exists($taxonomy->name, 'Location');
            if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null) {
                echo '<p> TERM ID is -> ' .$term.'TERM NAME is ->'.  $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
            }
    }
}  
?>
```

try this :P