# Include attachments with a custom taxonomy in search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search, attachments, pre-get-posts, post-status

I need to include attachments in the search. So far, I have managed this by hooking into `pre_get_posts` and checking if it's on the search results page, I add 'attachment' to the `post_type` and 'inherit' to the `post_status`, in order to also include attachments that are not attached to posts.

However, only attachments that have the custom taxonomy `download_category` set to any term should be included, attachments that do not have any download_category may not be seen in the search results.

How can I achieve that?

I have found this answer 
[Custom Taxonomy WP_Query for All Terms in a Taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy#answer-35611) and tried it out. While this does really only show those attachments with any download_category set, it applies to posts and pages as well, and as those never have the download_category taxonomy set, no pages and posts are shown in the search results...

So to clarify again what I need in short terms:
- include attachments in the search results, but only if they have taxonomy `download_category` set to any term
- Keep normal search functionality for pages and posts!

Comment: I have now been able to achieve what I need by hooking into `posts_clauses` and modifying the where and join clauses with regular expressions (ouch!). This is hacky as hell and I don't want to rely on it for the future, when a WP Update or additional plugin might change the basic query in a way that will break the whole functionality. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Another problem with the approach in my previous comment is that pagination is not working any longer... posts_found stays at a maximum of 10... O.o